# Why does this website is taking infinite time to load on Tor Broswer?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, circuit

http://www.hao123.com/

The above mentioned website is taking infinite time to load in the Tor Browser. However if I open it without using Tor, it loads instantaneously. Any guesses why this behavior?

Also can this circuit be debugged in some way using Tor Control Protocol, should browser based debugging be used.

Comment: I can not repdroduce your problem, the site is loading in the TBB. Try to refresh the identity of your TBB and try again.

Comment: This site is loading now but there may be some other sites which can take long time. So, How can we remove this problem by using time stamp?

Comment: Time stamp? I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I mean we can skip that website and go to next website if we are unable to fetch within 30 seconds like that because it may take lot of time if one site is not loading properly.